# Updating a xib view's position after a uiviewcontroller loads?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a simple UIViewController which has a corresponding .xib file.

```
ViewController *v = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:v animated:YES];
```

In this .xib file, I have a UILabel, which is positioned in the middle of the screen. I would like to move this label to a new position once the view is loaded, but before it is visible:

```
label.center = CGPointMake(0,0);
```

When I try putting the above code in the following methods, this is what happens:

- `initWithNibName:bundle`: position doesn't update
- `awakeFromNib`: position doesn't update
- `viewDidLoad`: position doesn't update
- `viewWillAppear`: position doesn't update
- `viewDidAppear`: position only updates after the view is fully loaded (i.e. the label's original position can be seen for a split second).

When I try updating something like the text property:

```
label.text = @"Foo";
```

... it works in all of these methods. For some reason, it is only the position that gets overridden by the .xib file.

When I say that "position doesn't update" I mean that when the label is shown on the screen, it is in the location defined in the .xib file rather than the one I am trying to override it with.

When I try to `NSLog` the position, it shows that it updates it correctly, but then when I check the position again in `viewDidAppear`, it shows the incorrect value. For example, say the .xib defines the x at 99, and I want to change it to 0:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    label.center = CGPointMake(0,0);
    NSLog(@"%f", label.center.x); // reports 0
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"%f", label.center.x); // reports 99 (Error: should be 0)
    label.center = resultLabelHiddenCenter;
    NSLog(@"%f", label.center.x); // reports 0
}
```

How can I update the label's center before the view is shown without any visual glitches?

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think , You are using `autoLayout` for your xib.

[image]

I have two solutions for you in my mind.

**First one is** , please don't  use `setFrame` or `setBounds` because `Autolayout`  will skip them.

Changing the constraints is the best solution .You can also add/remove extra constraints.

A good video  [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=202) is available in WWDC 2012 regarding `Autolayout` adjustments.

[image]

**Second one is**,Implement `viewDidLayoutSubviews` which will call just after the view controller's view's layoutSubviews method is invoked.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    @try
    {
         // reset label frame here.
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s\n exception: Name- %@ Reason->%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,[exception name],[exception reason]);
    }
}
```