# Fixing orientation problems with views ios 6

Tags: ios, ios6.1

I'm trying to create a simple ios 6 app. I've added a View and a Button inside my initial view controller, which was created by story board.

I'm trying to understand how orientation works with views/buttons/images/etc.

1. When I launch the simulator, the first problem I see is that it defaults to landscape for some reason. I would have expected the default to be portrait. How do I adjust this?
   In my view controller I have the following:

   -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
   }

   -(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
       return YES;
   }

   -(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
   {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; /* I get an implicit cast. I warning here too. */
   }

I've also tried modifying the Supported Interface Orientations in the Summary tab to support but no luck there either.

2. When I change the orientation through the simulator or my phone, the View disappears or becomes really thin. How do I keep the width at 100% no matter what orientation I'm in? I've attached a few screen shots.

This is how it's suppose to look:
[image]

But when I change the orientation, this happens:
[image]
[image]

Comment: check this out http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: see my answer.It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443452/set-keyboard-orientation-only-ios-6/15443637#15443637

Comment: if u are using autolayout , this answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458174/updating-a-xib-views-position-after-a-uiviewcontroller-loads/15458396#15458396

Comment: I still don't understand why my application defaults to landscape.

Answer (score 0):

The simulator will always launch in the first orientation listed under supported orientations in the plist. If you put landscape first it will launch in landscape mode.

For the resizing issue you will need to set a height constrain on the button. Go to storyboard , select the button, and then use the constrain menus at the botton of the storyboard view.